# Image store in laravel 8 with flutter

Tags: laravel, database, flutter, image

i'm trying to store image to my DB using laravel with flutter

this is my flutter code:

[image]

and this is what i get in file.path:

[image]

here my laravel code:

```
public function store(Request $request){
        dd(request->all);
        $input =$request->json()->all();
        $doctor = new AcceptDoctor();
        echo "before if";
        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
            echo "inside if";
            $path = $request->file('file')->store('images');
            $doctor-> signature_path = $path;
        }
        
        $doctor->save();
        return $doctor;
    }
```

this is the output:

[image]

dd output:

[image]

the if statement not working and i try to echo the signature_path is null
i try the same code using html it's work
what should i do?

Comment: Don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Comment: could you please explain it in little more detail, what is the issue you are facing? On certain conditions (like while create or update...) or on all cases?

Comment: @SarojShrestha when i post image

Comment: @YaraAbd what is the issue you are facing? What is the error message?

Comment: @SarojShrestha signature_path is null

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
    $path = $request->file('signature_path')->store('images');
    $doctor-> signature_path = $path;
}
```

This piece of code seems conflicting, first you check if `file` is available, and then you try to access `signature_path`. My guess, according to your error message, it should be:

```
if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
    $path = $request->file('file')->store('images');
    $doctor-> signature_path = $path;
}
```

if this doesn't work, paste the code:

```
dd($request->all());
```

on the very first line of `store` method and let us know

Comment: could you please `dd($request->all())` on first line inside `store` method and share the outcome?

Comment: @YaraAbd could you please share from `preview` tab instead of `response` tab

Comment: @YaraAbd you share dd output from `response tab`, instead share it from `preview tab` which is just left to response tab.

Comment: can you see the edit please?